# How to fulfill System.Composition MEF ImportingConstructor with an instance

Tags: c#, mef, composition

I'm using MEF (System.Composition from nuget) + Common.Logging and have classes that call ILog, e.g.,

```
[Export(typeof(ITranslator))]
public class ATranslator : BaseTranslator
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ATranslator(ILog log)
    {
...
    }
```

The logger instance is available from Common.Logging via `log = LogManager.GetLogger<ITranslator>();` but how do I plugin this into my composition container?

```
        var container = new ContainerConfiguration()
            .WithAssembly(typeof(ITranslator).Assembly)
            .CreateContainer();            
        container.SatisfyImports(this);
```

so that I can

```
    [ImportMany]
    private IEnumerable<ITranslator> Translators { get; set; }
```

without

> System.Composition.Hosting.CompositionFailedException : No export was
>   found for the contract 'ILog'  -> required by import 'log' of part
>   'ATranslator'  -> required by import 'item' of part 'ITranslator[]' 
>   -> required by initial request for contract 'IEnumerable { IsImportMany = True }'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to do the export to ILog as a property in other class?

```
public class LogExporter
{
    [Export(typeof(ILog))]
    public ILog Log
    {
        return LogManager.GetLogger<ITranslator>();
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can try to do it using [ComposeExportedValue Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd986608(v=vs.110).aspx) with code instead of attributes:

```
container.ComposeExportedValue<ILog>(LogManager.GetLogger<ITranslator>());
```

Comment: That is an interesting idea. How do I use LogExporter though?

Comment: I think it will work even if you do nothing with LogExporter, it is just a dummy class to export the property. Can you try it?

Comment: I just tried it, and it looks like it works, though I cannot understand how. :)

Comment: It is really reasonable, every time you compose MEF will look for an export attribute of ILog to fill the requirements of ILog import, it will find this property and will use it as the exported type.

Comment: @tofutim Updated my answer with another option.

Comment: So does it create a new instance of the class that holds the property? (LogExporter). Re: ComposeExportedValue (I do not see this is System.Composition - only in System.Component.Composition.)

Comment: I do not sure about your first question, the best idea is to create an parameterless constructor for LogExporter class and put inside it a break point, then you can debug it and see what happens. About your second question that is correct that ComposeExportedValue is declared in System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll but all others MEF parts resides there too, I did not understand what is the probelm about it?

Comment: I'm using the PCL version from nuget, System.Composition.

Comment: So I am not sure about the second option, but I think the first solved the problem :)